# what is the best way to create "one" to "one or two" relation in rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Lets suppose we have a football player, this player can have one or two teams ONLY, I mean he may be in a club team and/or a national team or nothing of them. what is the best way to do this in rails relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create `has_one` relationships for each team type. Perhaps you call one `club_team` and the other `national_team`. Don't make these relationships required. This would accomplish your goal of allowing 0, 1, or 2 relationships between players and teams.

You can accomplish this by renaming the relationship in your model. For instance, if you had a model named `FootballTeam` then you could have two relationships like this:

```
has_one club_team, :class_name => "FootballTeam"
has_one national_team, :class_name => "FootballTeam"
```

This would also provide you with methods like `player.club_team` and `player.national_team` if `player` were an instance of your player model.

Comment: Great, you mean i should create two models, national_team and club_team right?. but they share the same attributes and behavior exactly. should i implement them?

Comment: You actually don't need to create two models. Both teams can be instances of the "FootballTeam" model. If both types of teams share the same attributes and behavior then implementing it twice would violate the DRY principle of not repeating yourself. The whole reason you bother to rename the associations is so that you can refer to them by different names when they are actually instances of the same model.

Comment: One more question please :), How can i do it in database level? I mean the relations in the database?.

Comment: You need a club_team_id and a national_team_id in your `Players` table.

Answer (score 0):

All you'd need is a `:teams` column in your `Players` table that accepts a string of IDs that refer to teams. One digit means one team, two (comma-separated or whatever) digits means two, and none means none.

Comment: but the database insertion and queries will be so hard, and i think its not recommended in database world.